# AutoMapper use multiple value converters with same type

Tags: automapper

I want to do bool to string conversion in two different ways in my project. Something like:

```
CreateMap<bool, string>()
            .ConvertUsing(src => src ? "true" : "false");

CreateMap<bool, string>()
            .ConvertUsing(src => src ? "yes" : "no");
```

On some of the mappings I want to use the first converter and on others want to use the second converter. Would like to know if this is possible. If so how should I configure that. I Prefer not to use member level methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LucianBargaoanu
I already had a look at that but couldn't grab anything that works except on member level configurations.

Comment: A map is global, it applies everywhere. You _have_ to apply smth at the member level. You can use `ForAllMaps`, `ForAllMembers` or `ForAllPropertMaps` to automate that. How else would you do it? :)

Comment: I was looking for something like ValueTransformers which can be applied at Map level.

Comment: There's no such thing, but you can achieve smth similar with the API-s I mentioned.